# Error 9628 : Type (timestamp) not found in informix while creating new table

Tags: database, rdbms, informix

I'm trying to create a new database in informix using following query.

```
CREATE TABLE IDN_AUTH_SESSION_STORE (
        SESSION_ID LVARCHAR (100) DEFAULT NULL,
        SESSION_TYPE LVARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
        SESSION_OBJECT BLOB,
        TIME_CREATED TIMESTAMP,
        PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_ID, SESSION_TYPE)
);
```

When I ran this query, I am getting following error.

```
9628: Type (timestamp) not found.
```

What is the reason for this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, timestamp doesn't exist in Informix.  Use datatype 'datetime year to fraction' instead.